# Javascript inside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, templates, ecmascript-6

I want to reference a Javascript variable inside an HTML tag like this:

```
<ul data-target="#{this.state.name}"></ul>
```

but it doesn't seem like this is valid syntax. I know that this is possible in Coffeescript, but is there a similar syntax in Javascript? I'm using ES6.

Comment: What do you expect "this.state" of an HTML tag to be? Is this HTML at all, or is it a string literal inside your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that allow you to do string interpolation in ES6. The equivalent to [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#strings)'s

```
"<ul data-target=\"#{this.state.name}\"></ul>"
```

would be

```
`<ul data-target="${this.state.name}"></ul>`
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not possible without some framework, eg. Angular.

On the other hand you can set the attribute of the element using plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my-thingy").setAttribute("data-target", "someStateName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes. and concat the # with the state.name value.

```
<ul data-target={"#" + this.state.name}></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **As the doc says**
>
> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and
>   writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the
>   element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data
>   attribute.
>
> Refer:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Fetch the entire dataset object using the dataset property on the DOM element.

```
var eleDOM = document.getElementById('list');
```

`eleDOM.dataset`;

> fetch the individual property

```
eleDOM.dataset.data1;
```

> Modify the individual data properties

```
eleDOM.dataset.data1 = "modified";
```

```js
   //Fetch the entire dataset object using the dataset property on the DOM element.
var eleDOM = document.getElementById('list')
console.log(eleDOM.dataset);

//fetch the individual property
console.log(eleDOM.dataset.data1);

//Modify the individual data properties
eleDOM.dataset.data1 = "modified";
```

```html
   <ul id ='list' data-data1 = "Panner" data-data2="Cheese">
</ul>
```